# How to check if variable is not empty in xslt?

Tags: search-results, xslt

I am using sp 2010. I have a custom search result in xslt. I would like to check if "srportalurl" is not empty before show a ahref. If variable "srportalurl" is empty I would like show only the variable "srprojectname" without ahref. How to check if variable "srportalurl" is not empty?

```
<a>
                <xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="srportalurl" /></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="srprojectname" />
            </a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="srportalurl!= ''">
       <a>
            <xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="srportalurl" />
            <xsl:value-of select="srprojectname" />
        </a>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="srprojectname" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```